# Merge 2 algebraic expression using Sympy

Tags: sympy

How to merge 2 or more expressions
example: 3x + 2y - 2 and 2x + 3y -1  (3x + 2y -2 = 2x + 3y -1)
which gives x-y-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from sympy import *
# declare symbols
var("x, y")

# write the two expressions
expr1 = 3*x + 2*y - 2 
expr2 = 2*x + 3*y - 1

# subtract them
result = expr1 - expr2
result
# out: x - y - 1
```

EDIT: Alternatively, we can also create an `Equality` object and later rewrite it as an addition:

```py
eqaulity = Eq(expr1, expr2)
# out: 3*x + 2*y - 2 = 2*x + 3*y - 1
eqaulity.rewrite(Add)
# out: x - y - 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't know we could do it just by subtracting two expretions

Comment: I've edited the answer, so you can see two different approaches. Personally, I like more the first approach. Please, mark this answer as the solution to your question if it satisfies you! :)

Comment: Thanks again the different approach seems more standerd. Stack Overflow needs more people like you.